# How do I convert this 16bit value represented in hex into decimal using Python?

Tags: python, hex, can-bus

There is a 16bit value being sent from an ECU. It sends a high byte, then a low byte which is in the form of hex over CAN bus - A8F5. This value is representing the battery voltage connected to the ECU. How can this be decoded into a decimal value using Python?
The variable is read from a text file.
I have tried to use simple maths from other forums online but have not managed to find a value which would make any sense. The battery is being read at around 13V.

Comment: How is that variable stored? Is it a "A8F5" string?

Comment: Is that a byte string?

Comment: I was just reading them from a text file and then printing to the console using the syntax print(line[x]+line[x2]...line[xn])

Comment: Basic computer science questions you need to ask yourself: Is this an unsigned number or 16 bit 2's complement (or something else)? Since the target is using big endian, is that the same endianess as my desktop PC and if not do I need to convert it?

Comment: Anyway the number 13 clearly has no relation the number 0xA8F5/0xF5A8. So in order to do something meaningful with it at all, you need to know how the device documents what this number represents.

Comment: @Lundin well it must be unsigned given the value is greater than 32767. For anyone following, looks as though I need to calculate a coefficient to divide the returned value to produce the actual value

Comment: @Tom You can't tell if a number is signed or unsigned by looking at the raw binary.

Answer (score 0):

you can use easily the native function `int()` like this:

```
decimal = int("Your hex code", 16)
```

In your case if you need to read from text file you can do:

```
hex = open("hex.txt", "r").read()
decimal = int(hex, 16)
```

Comment: I tried that, it returns me a value of 43253

Comment: @Tom Yes, and...? Was that what you expected? If not, then what did you expect and why?